# Get max value of given date range and group by day PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am having so much trouble with this.  I am trying to get the maximum value per day given the range.  But I keep getting a blank value in my count column when I load the query result.

```
<?php

include("dbconnect.php");   

$link=Connection();


$data1 = '2016-04-29 00:00:00';
$data2 = '2016-05-02 00:00:00';



$result = mysql_query(
                          "
                          SELECT DATE(orderDate), MAX(Count)
                          FROM testLocation 
                          WHERE orderDate 
                          BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%'
                          GROUP BY DATE(orderDate)
                          "
                          ,$link
                          );
?>
```

Comment: The query looks fine. Must  be how you read the result

Comment: Just a quick hint: The mysql_* functions are deprecated and should not be used anymore. Instead use the mysqli_* Funktions or the PDO object.

Comment: When I do a query for all the values, the result displays fine but when I do this new query nothing displays.

Comment: What is '%' in your query good for? What is the data type for `orderDate`? And how do access the "count column"?

Comment: the % is unneccessary.  the orderDate is in timestamp

Comment: Assuming that $data1 and $data2 can be altered / chosen by the user, your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. It's better to use PDO with prepared statements. Check out http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: I understand that, This is just a test for the query to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to look at here.

First, the `%` signs in your date constants should not be there. Those only work with the `LIKE` operator.

Second, the `BETWEEN` operator works poorly for `DATETIME` values, because it is the equivalent of this:

```
     WHERE orderDate >= '$data1'
       AND orderDate <= '$data2'  -- wrong!
```

This excludes everything after precisely midnight on the ending date. `<=` is the wrong comparison to use for `DATETIME`.

You should use this instead:

```
     WHERE orderDate >= '$data1'
       AND orderDate <  '$data2' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

It includes everything up until, but not including, `<` midnight on the day *after* the end date you gave. That means it will include everything on the last day of your date range, which is presumably what you want.

Third, I suggest you give alias column names to the columns in your result set. That will make them easier for php code to retrieve.

```
               SELECT DATE(orderDate) orderDate, 
                      MAX(Count) maxCount
                FROM testLocation 
               WHERE orderDate >= '$data1'
                 AND orderDate <  '$data2' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
               GROUP BY DATE(orderDate)
```

Fourth, if your `testLocation` table has no records in it at all for a particular date, the result set from this query will omit that date.

Fifth (others mentioned this in comments) the `mysql_` API is not a good choice for your php programming; it's insecure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to please use PDO for the above queries.Your question is not fully clear but if you intend to retrieve database result whose value is maximum you can do the following way.

```
$sql='SELECT * FROM testLocation 
                      WHERE orderDate 
                      BETWEEN '$data1%' AND '$data2%' ORDER BY orderDate
                      DESC LIMIT 1';
```

By this query we have limited the retrieved data to be 1 and that is why you will get only the maximum value  here and mark we have ordered the data in descending manner.